# Will_paginate error undefined method `total_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

**I'm constantly getting the error when trying to paginate my products:**

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa19efed0c0>
```

I've tried lots of combinations but It still shows. I've also tried to `require 'will_paginate/array'` in an `initializer` and in `application controller` with no luck.

**¿Can someone help with this please?**

**Products Controller:**

```
  def from_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:cat_id])
    @products = Product.where(category_id: params[:cat_id])
    @filtered_products = @products.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**In erb view**

<%= will_paginate @filtered_products %>

**index.js.erb**

$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("products")) %>");

Comment: Might you try the kaminari gem instead of will_paginate? I think it's quite similar to use and maybe more commonly used, though not sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb

  def from_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:cat_id])
    @products = Product.where(category_id: params[:cat_id]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

For `erb` file you can use like:

```
<%= will_paginate @products %>
```

Can you please try like this?